# Winserver 2008, Powershell ISE, Takeown + Get-Variable

Tags: powershell, variables, directory, powershell-ise

working on a powershell script for modifying ownership of files. I ran an audit on my server and got all the directories that are needing ownership modified. My problem is that I can't figure out how to do takeown on multiple files at once. I've been adding each directory to a pre-typed (Takeown /f "" /A) but I'm sure there is a faster way to knock this out. I'm new to powershell scripts so bear with me..

```
takeown /f (Get-Variable) /A
Set-Variable "A:\file\file2\file3"
```

Like I said I have the list of directories, is there a way to run the script on repeat and get each each line of directories? *Note: I have 40,000 lines of directories to modify. We had a lot of removed users and I was tasked with cleaning up the network shared drive.*

Any help is greatly appreciated. Will update if I'm able to find a way before I get a response.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ive found a solution to my problem but StackOverflow refuses to let me post for some reason.

Basically I've set the variable then using the takeown command and inputting the variable within the line. I'll try to post it some other time but again, i keep getting an error when i hit submit.

Furthermore, I concated the lines together as needed in Excel to get the full command!

Comment: Why don´t you use the /r? https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown